# Get all view count of a page from different page links

Tags: php

I want to track view count of a page from different page links, but not page reload or refresh.

> I want to call this function when page viewed from various pages.

```
trackDifferentViewCount($Infos->user_id,'1','','1');
```

Answer (score 0):

A "refresh" is yet another page request. It does not differ from a regular page view. To filter those out, you would need to remember the last page the user visited, and if that page is the same page, you do not count it as distinct visit. You can use the session or a cookie for this.

This does mean though that if a user closes the browser and loads the same page again later, it would still not count as distinct visit, even though it is. There's no 100% foolproof way to handle this.